# How to open "Portlet Preferences" page of dialog in Liferay?

Tags: plugins, tags, liferay, liferay-theme

It is said in manual to CompactTags portlet, that user should "open preferences interface" after portlet installation (said [here](http://www.tune-it.ru/en/software-development/liferay-based-solutions/compacttags)).

If I press wrench icon, I get only "Look and Feel" and "Configuration" entries.

[image]

Is this mean that something wrong with my theme?

Comment: Preferences option appears when portlet has configured with edit mode in portlet.xml, portlet you are referring is not having that. There is code missing in portlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your portlet.xml, you'll have to support the portlet's "edit" mode. That's how the JSR-286 standard names the "Preferences" setting. IMHO Liferay's choice of "Preferences" is a better name than "edit", thus it's used on the user-facing interface.

In addition, the user in question must have permission to "edit" the portlet.

partial portlet.xml:

```
<portlet>
  ....
  <supports>
     <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
     <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
     <portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode> <!-- this is what you need -->
  </supports>
  ...
</portlet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Preferences option appears when portlet has configured with edit mode in portlet.xml, portlet you are referring is not having that. 
There is code missing in the portlet.